# Deserialize a top level list with Colander in Pyramid using Cornice

Tags: python, pyramid, colander, cornice

Given a POST request with `Content-Type: application/json` and a body of `["foo", "bar"]` how do I create a Colander schema in Pyramid using Cornice to deserialize this.

This is what I've come up with:

```
class SimpleList(colander.SequenceSchema):
    items = colander.SchemaNode(colander.String())
```

And it works great in the CLI with vanilla Colander. However, when I use it on a Cornice Service like so:

```
@simple_list_service.post(schema=SimpleList)
def simple_list_post(request):
    print(request.validated)
```

I get this:

```
{"errors": [{"name": "items", "description": "items is missing", "location": "body"}], "status": "error"}
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The current version of cornice only allows `colander.MappingSchema` for schema validation.  Anything else throws an exception (obviously you did this before that change was made as you got farther).

So, unless things change, you can't validate a list as input.